# Determining dimGrid and dimBlock sizes in CUDA

Tags: cuda

First off, I'm fairly new to CUDA programming so I apologize for such a simple question. I have researched the best way to determine dimGrid and dimBlock in my GPU kernel call and for some reason I'm not quite getting it to work.

On my home PC, I have a **GeForce GTX 580** (**Compute Capability 2.0**). 1024 threads per block etc. I can get my code to run properly on this PC. My gpu is populating the distance array of size 988*988. Here is part of the code below:

```
#define SIZE 988

__global__ void createDistanceTable(double *d_distances, double *d_coordinates)  
{
int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

if(row < SIZE && col < SIZE)
    d_distances[row * SIZE + col] = 
    acos(__sinf(d_coordinates[row * 2 + 0])*
   __sinf(d_coordinates[col * 2 + 0])+__cosf(d_coordinates[row * 2 + 0])*
   __cosf(d_coordinates[col * 2 + 0])*__cosf(d_coordinates[col * 2 + 1]-
   d_coordinates[row * 2 + 1]))*6371;
}
```

Kernel call in main:

```
dim3 dimBlock(32,32,1);
dim3 dimGrid(32,32,1);
createDistanceTable<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_distances, d_coordinates);
```

My issue is I simply have not found a way to get this code to run properly on my laptop.  My laptop's GPU is a **GeForce 9600M GT** (**Compute Capability 1.1**). 512 threads per block etc. I would greatly appreciate any guidance in helping my understand how I should approach the dimBlock and dimGrid for my kernel call on my laptop. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What do you mean by "I simply have not found a way to get this code to run properly on my laptop"?

Comment: By the way, Compute Capability 1.1 does not support double-precision floats (CC 1.3 and above).

Comment: The program will run but my distance array has the same value for all indices.  I guess I'm trying to understand if my laptop is capable of running this and if so, is there any suggestion on what I should try instead of dim3 dimBlock(32,32,1) and dim3 dimGrid(32,32,1).

Comment: Ah, so I guess that would be the issue with the incorrect populated data.

Comment: Did you use `cuda-memcheck` and some [error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)?

Comment: No.  The only errors I used was: if(cudaSuccess != err), where my cudaMemcpy and cudaMalloc's are set to err.

Comment: You can add architecture checking to a makefile (by running simple test file), so at compile time you will be able to set right values & also set some flags. If you wanna run the same binary file on different computers with the same processor architecture, you can do some tests at runtime. BTW, don't use `double` type and `double` functions directly! Better do some `typedef` and macros, so you'll be able run the same code on different architectures of GPU.

Comment: Moreover, you are using `sinf` and `cosf` which are single-precision functions (cf. [CUDA's documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html)). Which version of CUDA are you using?

Comment: CUDA 5.0.  I was trying to add the intrinsic trig functions instead of using math.h for all them.  __sin() wouldn't work though.

Comment: In compute capability 1.1 there is max 512 threads per block. `32 * 32 = 1024` so you need to change this (`dimBlock`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several things were wrong in your code.

1. Using double-precision on CC < 1.3.
2. The size of your thread blocks (as you said, CC <= 1.3 means 512 threads max per block, you used 1024 threads per block). I guess you could use `__CUDA_ARCH__` if you do need some multi-architecture code.
3. No error checking or memory checking (`cuda-memcheck`). You may allocate more memory than you have, or use more threads/blocks than your GPU can handle, and you will not detect it.

Consider the following example based on your code (I am using `float` instead of `double`):

```cpp
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>      // printf

#define SIZE 988
#define GRID_SIZE 32
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16 // set to 16 instead of 32 for instance

#define CUDA_CHECK_ERROR() __cuda_check_errors(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(err) __cuda_safe_call(err, __FILE__, __LINE__)

// See: http://codeyarns.com/2011/03/02/how-to-do-error-checking-in-cuda/
inline void
__cuda_check_errors (const char *filename, const int line_number)
{
  cudaError err = cudaDeviceSynchronize ();
  if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
      printf ("CUDA error %i at %s:%i: %s\n",
          err, filename, line_number, cudaGetErrorString (err));
      exit (-1);
    }
}

inline void
__cuda_safe_call (cudaError err, const char *filename, const int line_number)
{
  if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
      printf ("CUDA error %i at %s:%i: %s\n",
          err, filename, line_number, cudaGetErrorString (err));
      exit (-1);
    }
}

__global__ void
createDistanceTable (float *d_distances, float *d_coordinates)
{
  int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  if (row < SIZE && col < SIZE)
    d_distances[row * SIZE + col] =
      acos (__sinf (d_coordinates[row * 2 + 0]) *
        __sinf (d_coordinates[col * 2 + 0]) +
        __cosf (d_coordinates[row * 2 + 0]) *
        __cosf (d_coordinates[col * 2 + 0]) *
        __cosf (d_coordinates[col * 2 + 1] -
            d_coordinates[row * 2 + 1])) * 6371;
}

int
main ()
{
  float *d_distances;
  float *d_coordinates;

  CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaMalloc (&d_distances, SIZE * SIZE * sizeof (float)));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaMalloc (&d_coordinates, SIZE * SIZE * sizeof (float)));

  dim3 dimGrid (GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE);
  dim3 dimBlock (BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
  createDistanceTable <<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>> (d_distances, d_coordinates);

  CUDA_CHECK_ERROR ();

  CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaFree (d_distances));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaFree (d_coordinates));
}
```

Compilation command (change architecture accordingly):

> nvcc prog.cu -g -G -lineinfo -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -o prog

With 32x32 block on CC 2.0 or 16x16 on CC 1.1:

> ```
> cuda-memcheck ./prog 
> ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
> ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
> ```

With 33x33 block on CC 2.0 or 32x32 block on CC 1.1:

> ```
> cuda-memcheck ./prog 
> ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
> ========= Program hit error 9 on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch 
> ========= Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
> ========= Host Frame:/usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/libcuda.so [0x26a230]
> ========= Host Frame:/opt/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0 (cudaLaunch + 0x242) [0x2f592]
> ========= Host Frame:./prog [0xc76]
> ========= Host Frame:./prog [0xa99]
> ========= Host Frame:./prog [0xac4]
> ========= Host Frame:./prog [0x9d1]
> ========= Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xed) [0x2176d]
> ========= Host Frame:./prog [0x859]
> =========
> ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
> ```

Error 9:

> ```
> /**
> * This indicates that a kernel launch is requesting resources that can
> * never be satisfied by the current device. Requesting more shared memory
> * per block than the device supports will trigger this error, as will
> * requesting too many threads or blocks. See ::cudaDeviceProp for more
> * device limitations.
> */ cudaErrorInvalidConfiguration         =      9,
> ```